# How can I invoke a method from a Type or its derived Types?

Tags: c#, monodevelop

I'm trying to replicate `MonoBehaviour` of the Unity 3D engine. I'm using monodevelop on Linux, and most testing will be done in Windows.

More about `MonoBehavior.Start` can be read [here](http://docs.unity3d.ru/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html).

I want to invoke the `Start` method on all types which inherit from MonoBehavior.

This is what I have tried:

```
class MonoBehaviour
{
  static Type[] types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes();

  public static void Main ()
  {
    foreach (Type type in types)
    {
      if (type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(MonoBehaviour)))
      {
        MethodInfo minfo = type.GetMethod ("Start");
        mInfo.Invoke (type, null); // This throws
      }
    }
  }
}

class example : MonoBehaviour
{
  void Start()
  {
    // I want this to be run from MonoBehaviour
    Console.WriteLine ("HelloWorld");
  }
}

class example1 : MonoBehaviour
{
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** Completely redoing this answer as now I believe I know what you are asking.

I'm going to give you code that will allow you to call Start of every object of a Type in an assembly. However, I don't think this is how MonoBehavior works. There is more to consider. For example, `Awake` should be called first, and there is the condition of whether scripts have been enabled. Also, I don't think this method is called on all object at once, but perhaps only when the object is create/initiated. I do not have Unity 3D experience, so I'm ignorant to these details. I'm only relying on what I've read from the link in your question.

I've added some extra binding flags to show that this could find methods of various scopes. Also, in my code I am explicitly looking for `Start` methods that have no parameters. This can be modified to your needs and liking.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    Type[] types = asm.GetTypes();

    foreach (var type in types)
    {
      if (type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(MonoBehavior)) || type.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(MonoBehavior)))
      {
        MethodInfo startMethod = type.GetMethod("Start", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new Type[] { }, null);
        if (startMethod != null)
        {
          ConstructorInfo ctor = type.GetConstructor(new Type[] { });
          if (ctor != null)
          {
            object inst = ctor.Invoke(new object[] { });
            startMethod.Invoke(inst, new object[] { });
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

interface MonoBehavior
{
}

class Example1 : MonoBehavior
{
  static void Start()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Example1 Start");
  }
}

class Example2 : MonoBehavior
{
}
```

Now, if you don't like creating an object, you could make `Start` static, and a few lines in the reflection would be adjusted like this:

```
MethodInfo startMethod = type.GetMethod("Start", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static, null, new Type[] { }, null);
if (startMethod != null)
{
  startMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { });
}
```

Note that I no longer need to create an instance, and the first parameter passed to `Invoke` is null (this is always done for `static` methods).

However, I don't get the impression from reading the Unity3D doc on `MonoBehaviour.Start` that it is intended to run in this manner, let alone on static. I think it should be run when `MonoBehaviour` are created, under other various conditions. That model would not require reflection, but I would recommend building a type of factory model, where you are creating `MonoBeaviour` objects on requests to a factory object - which invokes the appropriate `Awake` and `Start` methods before returning the instance.

Comment: yes I want that start is called on other classes - not main on monoBehaviour class, but that MonoBehaviour class would start to run all the Start() functions in other classes just like in Unity 3D

Comment: yeey it works :) finally. Anyway why do you people never include on top using ..... whatever you are using so your code works. yesterday I was searching 20 minutes where `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly` lies. to figure out if that's even the thing I need for my needs. Anyway thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

A type is not its own subclass, that's why you have three types but only 2 match the condition. (If that was the question.) Besides, MonoBehaviour doesn't have a Start() method, or I'm very tired ;-).

Comment: if you derive out of mono Start will run on start. I'm asking how do I run those Start methods, from MonoBehaviour

Comment: You comment "I get error here how do I solve this". That's not very specific. Is it a compilation error? A runtime error? What's the message?